# Prove: $\cot x=\sin x\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)+\cos^2x\,\cot x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Prove: $$\cot x=\sin x\,\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)+\cos^2x\,\cot x$$

Hi there! So this problem asks to prove this trigonometric identity.  I am not sure how to approach these problems other than needing to know the quotient,p ythagorean, and reciprocal identities.  From here I can see that $\cot x$ can be changed to $1/\tan x$, but is it really necessary? If someone could help with this, it'd be very appreciated!

Comment: *Hint:* Transform everyhing with $\sin x$  and $\cos x$ and factor out what you can.

Comment: so change the cos^2x to 1-sin^2x and sin to csc?

Comment: Take common $\cot x$ from RHS and use the identity $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$ to get the LHS form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\textrm{RHS}=\sin x\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)+\cos^2 x\cot x=\sin x\cos x+\cos^2 x\cot x\\ =\cot x(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)=\cot x=\textrm{LHS}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\cot x = \sin x \sin(π/2−x)+\cos ^2 x \cot x $$
$$= \sin ⁡x \sin⁡(π/2−x) + \cos^2 ⁡x \cot ⁡x$$
$$= \sin x \cos x + \cos^2 x \left(\frac{\cos x} {\sin x}\right)$$
$$= \frac{\sin^2 x \cos x + \cos x (\cos^2 x)} {\sin x}$$
$$= \frac{\cos x (\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)} {\sin x}$$
$$= \frac {\cos x (1)} {\sin x}$$
$$= \frac {1} {\tan x}$$
$$= \cot x$$